# How get my controller to make GET request when tab is selected?

Tags: angularjs

I am pretty new to angular and I am working on a data entry web page.  The web page has three tabs.  Vendor, Products and Types.  I started working on the Types tab first.  I'd be happy if I could just display the results of a GET request to my Rest API.  My Rest API works:

```
# curl http://192.168.1.115:8080/type 
[
 {"_id":"56415e7703aba26400fcdb67","type":"Skiing","__v":0},
 {"_id":"56417a8503aba26400fcdb68","type":"Bannana","__v":0},
 {"_id":"56417a8d03aba26400fcdb69","type":"Carrot","__v":0},
 {"_id":"56417a9603aba26400fcdb6a","type":"Beer","__v":0}
]
```

Here's the pertinent part of my html *UPDATED* I now have `st-safe-src=all_types`but still no joy ...

```
          <div ng-controller="typeCtrl" class="tab-pane" id="types-v">
            <p>The number {{3 + 4}}.</p>
            <p>message is {{message}}</p>
            <table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="all_types" class="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in displayedCollection">
                        <td>{{x.type}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div> <!-- end Types Tab -->
```

... and here is my `typeCtrl.js` ...

```
app.controller("typeCtrl", function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.type_to_look_for = "";
    $scope.message = "this is the message. (from typeCtrl)";
    $scope.itemsByPage=15;
    $scope.all_types = function () {
        $http.get("http://192.168.1.115:8080/type").then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        });
    }
});
```

... but when I click on the `Types` tab my data does not display.  I looked developer console and I do not even see the GET request kickoff. And my web page looks like this ...

[image: Not type data displayed :(]

... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What calls `all_types()`? You should probably `return` the promise created by `$http`, ie `return $http.get(...`; at the moment, it doesn't return anything. That and / or assign something to the `$scope` on completion

Comment: There is nothing that calls `all_types`. Assign `all types` from response by running `http.get` directly without scope

Comment: As per st-table documentation st-table should be assigned the collection as **st-table="rowCollection"** and you need to call $http directly without inside on any function and need to assign the data to the collection variable used in st-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that calls all_types. Run `http.get` and assign the response to `all_types`

```
app.controller("typeCtrl", function($scope,$http) {
$scope.type_to_look_for = "";
$scope.message = "this is the message. (from typeCtrl)";
$scope.itemsByPage=15;
$http.get("http://192.168.1.115:8080/type").then(function(response) {
    $scope.all_types = response;
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want a get request to be fired whenever you click on the Types tab, right? If so, just use `ng-click` to call your `all_types` function as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="typeCtrl" ng-click="all_types()" class="tab-pane" id="types-v" >
```

Also, you do not need to return response.data in your controller. Just assign the data to a scope object and use it in the template.

And finally, I would suggest wrapping all your ajax calls in factories and then inject those factories in your controllers.

Comment: Ok, how about calling the function by default in the controller? Just add $scope.all_types(); at the end of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

```
<div ng-controller="typeCtrl" class="tab-pane" id="types-v">
            <p>The number {{3 + 4}}.</p>
            <p>message is {{message}}</p>
            <table st-table="types" class="table table-striped"><!-- Do not need st-safe-src -->
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in types"><!-- Use the Collection name as types-->
                        <td>{{x.type}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

Controller Code

```
app.controller('typeCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.type_to_look_for = "";
    $scope.message = "this is the message. (from typeCtrl)";
    $scope.itemsByPage=15;
    $http.get("http://192.168.1.115:8080/type").then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.types = response.data;
    });
});
```

Here is working the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AXftFZolVHXcbtNzk7se?p=preview)

Comment: But it is not a good practice to call $http directly from controller.

Comment: You wrote "But it is not a good practice to call $http directly from controller" <-- Why?